# Adding association for location with city or zip code when using PostGIS to add markers using geography?

Tags: postgis, google-maps, google-maps-api, api, geography-data-type

On my front end, I am using google maps JS api.  I am adding markers, the google maps event gives me the lat/lng for where I add the marker.

I'm adding that marker into my postgres database:

```
INSERT INTO markers(created_by, title, description, lat, lng, geography)\
values($1, $2, $3, $4::decimal, $5::decimal, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($5::decimal, $4::decimal), $6))
```

Now, I have the marker added into my database and from the front end I can show the user which markers are within a mile or whatever of his current location.

However, I would like to start showing results by zip code or the city associated with the user's current location.

For example, let's say I am adding this latLng to my database: `37.555880, -122.325580`.  In my table I'm just going to add these points and the geography.  But, this is in the city of San Mateo, CA, and the zip code is 94402....

How can I add this information to my database given just the lat and long?

If it isn't possible, then I will look into using the reverse geocoding API from Google going forward for future points, so I can get this information from the front end itself and insert it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. a source that'll refer too [A generic solution to PostGIS nearest neighbor](http://www.bostongis.com/printerfriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor_generic) provides an approach

> "I have come up with a faster and more generic solution to calculating nearest neighbors"

For example, the author provides this query to answer, "For each street segment in zip 02109 list the 2 nearest fire stations and the distance in meters from each fire station. Order results by street name, street id and distance from nearest fire station "

> SELECT g1.gid as gid_ref, g1.street, g1.fraddl, g1.toaddl, f.name,   g1.nn_dist as dist_meters, g1.nn_gid
>   FROM (SELECT b.*,
>
>       (pgis_fn_nn(b.the_geom, 1000000, 2,1000,'fire_stations', 'true', 'gid',   'the_geom')).*
>       FROM (SELECT * FROM census2000tiger_arc where zipl = '02109') b) As g1, fire_stations f
>       WHERE f.gid = g1.nn_gid
>       ORDER BY g1.street, g1.fraddl, g1.gid, g1.nn_dist

Also, as an additional resource that you may find useful, [US Zip Codes from 2013 Government Data](https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666)

Comment: Thanks!  That's so awesome.  In my case, since I want some really up to date data, is it better that in the future that I just use the google geocoder from my front end to send the necessary data over?

Comment: I would say that's a good approach, IMO.